# Rotate a player controlled door in both directions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Important:**

> I started a post here
>   [Rotate a door in both directions in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662998/rotate-a-door-in-both-directions-in-unity)
>   I created a fully automatic door when interacting with it.

Now I want a door, that gets openend by the player and closed by the player. You can set a bool which makes the door always rotate away from the player.

The door rotation will start when calling the method `Interact()`. I call this method from another script. So for this moment, the method just gets called **once**.

```
[SerializeField]
    Vector3 openRotation; // door rotation when opened

    [SerializeField]
    float duration; // opening speed (duration)

    [SerializeField]
    bool isClosable; // door can be closed again?

    [SerializeField]
    Vector3 pivotPosition; // position of the pivot point

    [SerializeField]
    bool opensAwayFromPlayer; // always open away from the player

    bool isActive = false; // door is "busy" ?

    Transform doorPivot; 

    Transform playerTransform;

    bool isOpen = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        playerTransform = Globals.GetPlayerObject().transform;
        doorPivot = new GameObject().transform;
        doorPivot.position = pivotPosition;
        transform.SetParent(doorPivot);
    }

    public void Interact() // Interact with the door and start opening / closing it
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoorRotation());
    }

    void IEnumerator DoorRotation()
    {
        if (isActive) // return if already active
            yield break;

        isActive = true;

        float counter; // current rotation counter

        Vector3 defaultAngles = doorPivot.eulerAngles;

        Vector3 desiredRotation = this.openRotation; // the target rotation

        if (opensAwayFromPlayer && PlayerIsBehindDoor(transform, playerTransform)) // if behind door -> change direction
            desiredRotation = -desiredRotation;

        Vector3 openRotation = transform.eulerAngles + desiredRotation; // the final rotation

        if (!isOpen) // open if closed
        {
            counter = 0;
            while (counter < duration)
            {
                counter += Time.deltaTime;
                LerpDoorRotation(doorPivot, defaultAngles, openRotation, counter, duration); // open the door
                yield return null;
            }

            if (!isClosable) // if not closing again, destroy the script
                Destroy(this);
        }
        else // close the door
        {
            counter = duration;
            while (counter > 0)
            {
                counter -= Time.deltaTime;
                LerpDoorRotation(doorPivot, defaultAngles, openRotation, counter, duration); // close the door
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        isOpen = !isOpen; // Toggle door state

        isActive = false; // Door is not "busy"
    }

    bool PlayerIsBehindDoor(Transform door, Transform player) // Check if the player is in front or behind the door
    {
        Vector3 doorTransformDirection = door.forward.normalized;
        Vector3 playerTransformDirection = (player.position - door.position).normalized;
        return Vector3.Dot(doorTransformDirection, playerTransformDirection) < 0;
    }

    void LerpDoorRotation(Transform doorPivot, Vector3 defaultAngles, Vector3 targetRotation, float counter, float duration) // Door Rotation
    {
        doorPivot.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(defaultAngles, targetRotation, counter / duration);
    }
```

So this door has a really weird behaviour. It is not opening and closing correctly. I created a gif showing the behaviour when interacting with the door.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/165027329981153280/369749092638916608/doors.gif

The door opens twice and then changes its target angles.